# When Using select2 , select box hide automatically

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5" id="old_customer" style="display: block;>
    <label for="customersID" class="control-label">Customer </label>
    <select name="customersID"  id="customersID" onchange="getCustomersDue()"  >
        <option value="">Select Customer </option>
        <?php
        foreach($customers as $p)
        {
            $selected = ($p['customersID'] == $this->input->post('customersID')) ? ' selected="selected"' : "";

            echo '<option value="'.$p['customersID'].'" '.$selected.'>'.$p['name']."-".$p['mobile'].'</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

```
 $("#customersID").select2();
```

I'm getting all customers from database , and using select2 search and select the item . But when I select something , the entire div hides, and I cannot re-select anything . But the value remains in the page . Any solution will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use below the code for onchange. Remove this code `onchange="getCustomersDue()"`

```
$('#customersID').on('select2:select', function(e) {
    console.log('Selecting: ' , e.params.args.data);
});
```

Read this

https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

Comment: Still having the same problem . @Vel

Comment: please create a fiddle